# svn global ignore problems

Tags: svn

I have "[Bb]in" in my Global Ignore pattern.  I was hoping this would prevent somebody from accidentally comitting this folder in any way.  But I noticed I can still right click on that folder and do a "Add to Subversion".   Is there a way to prevent this? What exactly does this global pattern do.  I'm assuming it will apply to all projects.  thanks,

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot "deny" something to be committed.

Ignore just removes files that satisfy mask from `status` command and commands like `svn add *`.